# Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning,
I am running crazy trying one of the my first php codes with mysql. I have tested this on two servers, one hosted somewhere else and also using a local wamp server, the results are the same so I must have something bad in the code creating the connection or later when I run the query.

For wamp I have already verified the php.ini and also the MySQL privileges, in the code I am using the credentials stated there. I would appreciate some guidance.

```
 <?php

 // Function: connect to a database. Returns the database connection.




  function connect_db($host, $id, $pwd)
  {

  $connection = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password')
        or die('connection problem:' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('database_db');
    return $connection;
    if (!$connection)
  {
    print ("internal error " . mysql_errno() );
  }
  }

 //get names from form

$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$Event= $_POST['Event'];
$Date = $_POST['Date'];
$Time = $_POST['Time'];
$Venue= $_POST['Venue'];
$TypeID= $_POST['TypeID'];
$Score= $_POST['Score'];
$Member = $_POST['Member'];

//insert values
$myquery = "INSERT INTO Results(ID, Event, Date, Time, Venue, TypeID, Score, Member )VALUES('$ID', '$Event', '$Date', '$Time', '$Venue', '$TypeID', '$Score', '$Member')";
$answer = mysql_query($myquery);

if (!$answer) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $myquery;
    die($message);
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($answer)) {
    echo "Your results were entered successfully";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['Id'];
    echo $row['Event'];
    echo $row['Date'];
    echo $row['Time'];
    echo $row['Venue'];
    echo $row['TypeID'];
    echo $row['Score'];
    echo $row['Member'];
}
```

?>

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @Quentin, can you elaborate? As said before this is my first experience with programming. At this stage I need the fix the connection to the database. The API thing can be sorted later, I have no plans to publish this work.

Comment: There are several links in the comment that elaborate.

Comment: @Joy as Quentin picked up in my answer, your error message states the connection hasn't provided a username and password, yet in your code you have a username and password - have you provided the correct code and the correct error message?

Comment: @Ryan I have used the same username and password as stated on http://localhost/phpmyadmin/. I have checked and the user has ALL PRIVILEGES to the database too...

Comment: The fact is you can't of, you're getting `Access denied` which means either the user doesn't exist, the password is wrong, or the user isn't permitted to access the database from the server that the script is running on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change 'username' and 'password' to your actual credentials in your `mysql_connect` call.

Unless of course, those are your desired credentials - then you need to ensure that the user actually exists and has permission to access the database.

As a side note, use of `mysql_*` functions is deprecated and it's recommended to use `mysqli_*` or prepared statements.

Comment: But the error message says that there is no password being used, not that the password is wrong.

Comment: I have done that in the actual code, but I wouldn't paste them in a public forum ;)

Comment: Then you need to check your credentials.

Comment: I find it odd in the message that the username is empty while it is in the code and that I get a similar problem on the public server as on the local server...(of course I am using different credentials for each!)

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting the error from an alternative script?

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\wamp\www\blabla\blabla.php on line 34
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0048 381720 {main}( ) ..\blabla.php:0
2 0.0049 382440 mysql_query ( ) ..\blabla.php:34

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `connect_db`?

Comment: the function is only where you see it, do I need to call it again? Copy pasting the whole function or just call it? (I know, extremely rookie questions :) )

Comment: Any code within a function will only be executed when it is called, for example `connect_db()`. That must be called before executing your query so that the connection is active. Also - you're taking in 3 parameters to your function, so you will either need to remove those if you're hardcoding in the parameters for `mysql_connect()`, or pass over the `$host, $id, $pw` parameters to the function and use those in `mysql_connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

try to given access table to user :

```
grant all On [tabelName] to [userName];
```

example

```
grant all On mysql.* to root;
```